# Matplotlib stacked histogram using `scatter_matrix` on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

Currently I have the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

df= pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
colors = list('r' if i==1 else 'b' for i in df['class']) # class is either 1 or 0
plt.figure()
scatter_matrix(df, color=colors )
plt.show()
```

It shows the following output

[image]

But in this plot on diagonals, instead of simple histogram I want to show stacked histogram like the following such that for class '1' it is red and for '0' it is blue

[image]

Please guide me how can I do this ?

Comment: there is package called `seaborn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of seaborn is probably highly beneficial for plotting a scatter matrix kind of plot. However, I do not know how to plot a **stacked** histogram easily into the diagonal of a `PairGrid` in seaborn.
As the question anyways asks for matplotlib, the following is a solution using pandas and matplotlib. Unfortunately it will require to do a lot of stuff by hand. The following would be an example (note that seaborn is only imported to get some data since the question did not provide any).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# seaborn import just needed to get some data
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("iris")


n_hist = 10
category = "species"
columns = ["sepal_length","sepal_width","petal_length","petal_width"]
mi = df[columns].values.min()
ma = df[columns].values.max()
hist_bins = np.linspace(mi, ma, n_hist)


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(columns), ncols=len(columns), 
                         sharex="col")

for i,row in enumerate(columns):
    for j,col in enumerate(columns):
        ax= axes[i,j]
        if i == j:
            # diagonal
            mi = df[col].values.min()
            ma = df[col].values.max()
            hist_bins = np.linspace(mi, ma, n_hist)
            def hist(x):
                h, e = np.histogram(x.dropna()[col], bins=hist_bins)
                return pd.Series(h, e[:-1])
            b = df[[col,category]].groupby(category).apply(hist).T
            values = np.cumsum(b.values, axis=1)
            for k in range(len(b.columns)):
                if k == 0:
                    ax.bar(b.index, values[:,k], width=np.diff(hist_bins)[0])
                else:
                    ax.bar(b.index, values[:,k], width=np.diff(hist_bins)[0],
                           bottom=values[:,k-1])
        else:
            # offdiagonal
            for (n,cat) in df.groupby(category):
                ax.scatter(cat[col],cat[row], s = 5,label=n, )
        ax.set_xlabel(col)
        ax.set_ylabel(row)
        #ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sample code

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.pairplot(df, hue="species")
```

[image]

Comment: there is seaborn and bokeh also which can do this but I wanted to work with matplotlib somehow. Is it possible in matplotlib ? Thanks anyways

Comment: Unfortunately this answer does not plot **stacked** histograms. If someone has a good solution for plotting stacked histograms in a seaborn pair grid, I'd be happy to see it.